# Pandas KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask]) for me but not others with same code

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, spyder

I get this error that my professor does not get, running the identical, sample code he provided for our class.  I have not found a solution here or in the Anaconda or Python Tutor lists.

We're learning basic python, looking at the simplest Pandas DataFrames and learning to select columns.  We built a dataframe df (5 rows, 5 columns) and all but one line of the code works fine.  The line that doesn't work is:

```
df[ [0,1] ]
```

It continually, on my system, throws this KeyError on the `df[ [0,1] ]` command.  I get the analogous error for `df[ [0] ]` or `df[ [1] ]`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-c392a914e584>", line 1, in <module>
    df[ [0,1] ]

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1958, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2002, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)

  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1231, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])

KeyError: '[0 1] not in index'
```

It feels to me like something about how Python is installed on my computer.  I have Anaconda Navigator 1.7.0 installed under 64-bit Win 7 Pro.  I have restarted both Anaconda and Sypder directly many times and rebooted many times over many days.  Same error.  I updated Anaconda today.  Same error.  I'm running spyder, either through anaconda navigator or directly from the start menu - same error.  As I mentioned before, my professor has no problem running this same code.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what could be wrong that this one thing doesn't work on my computer?  My code example below includes a couple other column selections I AM able to do on my machine, so I think the DataFrame is working in general.

One thing I notice is that my path is quite long, because of the way this PC is set up.  I wonder if that could be part of the problem.

**Sample Code - from professor**, works for him, and all but the last line work fine for me, too.

```
#%%

import pandas

#%% data frame from dictionary

raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', ".", 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, ".", "."],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}


df = pandas.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

df

#%% select the 'first_name' column

b =df['first_name']

b.tolist()

#%% select multiple columns

df[ ['first_name', 'last_name'] ]


#%% select the first 2 columns (by column index - FAILS FOR ME)
# (THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR LISTED ABOVE)

df[ [0,1] ]
```

Additional code I tried - these work, too.

```
#%% prove that the columns are there

print(df.columns)

#%% select multiple columns by column name

b = df[ ['first_name', 'last_name'] ]

print(b)

#%% select same columns by sub-setting column list

c = df[ df.columns[0:2] ]

print(c)
```

Any ideas for how to fix this? Any other information I can provide to help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OxcOde - I noticed that, too.  I have the comma in my code `df[ [0,1] ]`, so don't know why it is missing in the error.  Isn't the index built-in?  (BTW, I wasn't allowed to comment on your answer, so am commenting here instead.)

Comment: When I try the same thing for just the first column: `df[ [0] ]`, I get the analogous error:  

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-16364f7b21e3>", line 1, in <module>
    df[ [0] ]

  <...snip...>

  File "C:\Users\kdm5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1231, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])

KeyError: '[0] not in index'

Answer (score 0):

check the version of pandas in both machines.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Comment: OK, I'll ask my professor and classmates to do that so we can see.  Thanks for the suggestion and how to do it!

Comment: My professor has pandas version 0.19.2 and Python version is 3.6.0 .  His works.

I have pandas version 0.20.3 and Python version 3.6.3 and mine doesn't work.

So we do have different versions.  How can this help me?

Comment: You have a newer version, may be you have hit a bug.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  Is anyone else with pandas version 0.20.3 and Python version 3.6.3 able to reproduce this erro?r

Comment: I created an environment on my own machine using Python 3.6.0 and Pandas 0.19.2, same as my prof.  I can run the same script fine in that environment, but continue to get the error under Python 3.6.3 and Pandas 0.20.3.  I agree this could be a bug.  How does one report a possible bug?

Comment: @fiberhabit the latest release version of pandas is 0.22.0 you need to check if the issue is resolved in this version. Then you just need to use the latest version. No need to report any bug. If you find issue you can report it on GitHub repo of pandas

Comment: thanks for this tip.  I have upgraded to pandas 0.22.0 and python 3.6.4 (through anaconda3 5.1.0), but sadly the error is still happening.  It is not solved by pandas 0.22.0.  So I should report it somehow?  Clearly I have not done this before.

Comment: Yes please report in pandas GitHub repository issues with minimal reproducible example